# Conda forge nbconvert package without pandoc?

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

**Background**

On the quest to build a really lightweight base jupyter notebook image, I was a bit surprised by how large the unpacked miniconda + jupyter-notebook installation is. Poking around in the deployed files seems to show that a big chunk (> 130MB) of it is pandoc.

Tracing through where it's used, it's the nbconvert package - the docs (https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) seem to indicate that usually pandoc must be installed independently.

As I'm using conda as the package manager here, checking out the conda forge history (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/nbconvert/) seems to suggest that the dependencies for the package changed between v4.2.0 and v5.1.1 to require pandoc.

**Question**

Does anyone know what the underlying reason for this becoming a dependency in the conda package is? And/or can redirect me to a better place to ask the question?

Comment: Pandoc is used, e.g., when you download a Notebook as a PDF. It may be used in other places as well. You can try to uninstall it after installing Jupyter, `conda remove pandoc`, and see what breaks :-)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that doesn't work really, as the dependency management kicks in and all the parent packages (nbconvert and notebook) will also be removed...

Comment: If you add the `--force` flag, it won't remove dependencies.